# Half of JavaScript won't execute in nested if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript and was asked to complete a nested if question. I found that I'm having trouble executing the second part. When you choose 'B', it's all good but when you choose 'G', you only get to type in a variable for the first statement and then it justs ends there.

Also, is it possible to write multiple nested if statements? As in let's say in the code below, after I told them "Work sucks...", can I continue to prompt the user to enter a variable?

Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var ans;
      var b1;
      var g1;

      ans = prompt ("How are you feeling?\n'B' for Bad | 'G' for Good");

      if (ans == 'B')
      {
        b1 = prompt ("I'm sorry ... 'W'.\nIf not, type 'E'");

        if (b1 == 'W')
        {
          window.alert ("Work sucks ...."); 
        }
        else if (b1 == 'E')
        {
          window.alert ("Here's ..");
        }
      }
      else if (ans == 'G')
      {
        g1 == prompt("That's great! I hope you have a fantastic day ahead!\n'C' to Continue | 'R' to Exit");
        if (g1 == 'C')
        {
          window.alert ("...");
        }
        else if (g1 == 'R')
        {
          window.alert ("Goodbye. Have a lovely day!");
        }
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An `if` statement is not a loop, but a `condition`!

Comment: @MarkFrankli ops, sorry, that's a typo!

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo in your code. For assignment, it has to be `g1 =` and not `g1 ==`

```js
var ans;
var b1;
var g1;

ans = prompt("How are you feeling?\n'B' for Bad | 'G' for Good");

if (ans == 'B') {
  b1 = prompt("I'm sorry ... 'W'.\nIf not, type 'E'");

  if (b1 == 'W') {
    window.alert("Work sucks ....");
  } else if (b1 == 'E') {
    window.alert("Here's ..");
  }

} else if (ans == 'G') {
  g1 = prompt("That's great! I hope you have a fantastic day ahead!\n'C' to Continue | 'R' to Exit");

  if (g1 == 'C') {
    window.alert("...");

  } else if (g1 == 'R') {
    window.alert("Goodbye. Have a lovely day!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh dear, thank you! I don't know how I could've missed that!

Comment: @Maya - No worries. Can happen :)